# Angular 2 router with login guard

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been trying to implement an authentication guard for a couple days now, but I'm still unable to get my `canActivate` function to run. My authentication guard looks like this (which obviously isn't actually guarding anything):

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor() {}

  canActivate():Observable<boolean>|boolean {
    console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called');
    return true;
  }
}
```

And my app component which imports the guard and implements the router looks like:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';
import 'rxjs/Rx'; // load the full rxjs

import { CharacterListComponent } from './characters/character-list.component';
import { VehicleListComponent } from './vehicles/vehicle-list.component';


import { LoggedInGuard } from './login.guard.ts'

@Component({
  selector: 'story-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    LoggedInGuard
  ]
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/characters', name: 'Characters', component: CharacterListComponent, useAsDefault: true },
  { path: '/vehicles', name: 'Vehicles', component: VehicleListComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard] }
  ])
export class AppComponent { }
```

Each time the `LoggedInGuard`'s `canActivate` function is run, a log entry should be made. When navigating between links a log entry is never made, meaning the function is never run. You can see the Plunker in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/i8TwERzzge5eOfbhg7BL?p=preview).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated... I'm sure this will be an easy one for someone more familiar with Angular 2.

Comment: Hey am also having the same issue did you find any solution for this please share

Comment: @Sujithrao what version of Angular 2 are you running? There are tons of releases out there and you can find documentation (in the form of blog posts, youtube videos, and SO questions) for many of them. Make sure you're using Angular 2.x.x (and NOT a release-candidate), don't try to implement examples from before September 15th 2016, and try to use the [official angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a way old version of Angular 2, Try upgrading your application to RC6 if possible,

You may look into newer references,

[Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Also angular team has created  [Plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html) showcasing the concepts. including authentication guard.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Oops! I've been using 2.0.0-beta.17 locally (which I'm pretty sure is RC6, right?), and I've updated the Plunker to do the same. I've also simplified my Plunker example, and will update my original question to reflect that. My issue still persists, and I will be extremely grateful for any more insight

Comment: No its not [2.0.0-beta.17](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta17-2016-04-28) is way old, Current version is RC6, check the Plunker I have added in the answer on how to setup the same.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for that link... I've worked with that Plunker before, and it's very helpful! I'm unable to utilize Node and npm in my project, so my implementation will have to be a bit different, but I'll upgrade to RC6 and if all goes well, you'll have the answer :)

Comment: Yeeah, There's so much confusion because of the landslide changes in Angular 2 versions. Wouldn't it be nice if one could delete all Angular 2 prerelease Q&A from SO?